# Visual Studio 2015 IntelliSense not displaying all methods

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 from 2013 because for some reason 2013 would not work on Windows 10 for me, even after multiple install attempts.

The only issue is IntelliSense is not displaying methods from other forms. For example, when I start typing one of the names of one of my forms, the only thing IntelliSense displays is:
[image]

However, the form has dozens of public methods, and the IntelliSense worked fine before in 2013.

Interestingly, I can still call the method if I remember the name by manually typing it, i.e. `Form1.TestMethod()`.

Does anyone know the fix for this? I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem and opened a support incident with Microsoft. They have verified per their answer below, that this is a bug with VS 2015 Update-1.  We have a few computers running with just VS 2015(no update 1) that work just fine.  I will pass along any further information that I receive from Microsoft.

Response from Microsoft:

> "*Yes this happens only with Visual Studio 2015 update1. It seems to
>   be a bug in VS2015 Update1, I am discussing with product team to fix
>   this issue.*
>
> *If you just avoid using default instance of forms. Creating a form instance, storing it in a local variable or field, and passing those
>   references around is easy enough. It's also a much better practice
>   that will make your code stronger overall.*
>
> *Dim f As New Form2*
>
> *f.TextBox1.Text = "Hi"*

Comment: Has this bug been fixed yet? It's awfully annyoing