# VB.Net intellisense is returning form classes, rather than My.Forms.etc

Tags: vb.net, forms

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I haven't even a clue how to google the description on this one - the above title returns nothing.

When typing an existing form name into VB.Net, for example `frmMainGame`, it's picking it up as a class. The text turns Cyan (Dark Theme) and has relevant options as `.ActiveForm`, `.DefaultFont`, `.DockPaddingEdges`, `.MousePosition`, etc.

Whereas pre-existing `frmMainGame`'s I've previously written out are working fine with the sub-controls found in the `frmMainGame` form. Needless to say, too, that these sub-controls and the typical long list of available options for a Form are not available.

This is happening in all subs, functions, either public or private. It's a project-wide occurrence.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]
In this image, the newly written frmMainGame. is resulting in cyan text.

[image]
Meanwhile, pre-existing code for frmMainGame has full access to the form and it's sub-controls. (Text boxes, etc, as found in Design view).

Meanwhile, the class code itself looks fine;

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class frmMainGame
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
    Me.GameTimer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
    Me.GameMsgBox = New System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()
    Me.GameMsgFilter = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox()
    Me.PicWorldMap = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
    Me.mapAreaTitle = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.lblCrafting = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.barHP = New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar()
    Me.barMagic = New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar()
    Me.barStamina = New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar()
    Me.barHunger = New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar()
    Me.barThirst = New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar()
    Me.barRest = New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar()
    Me.picPortrait = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
    Me.picScene = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
    Me.picSky = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
    Me.lblTimeNormal = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblTimeFast = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblTimeFaster = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblTimeDate = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.ActionList = New System.Windows.Forms.ListView()
    Me.ColumnHeader2 = CType(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader(), System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)
    Me.lblCharSheet = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblCurrentAction = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.TM_Walk = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
    Me.TM_run = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
    Me.TM_sprint = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
    Me.lblOptions = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblSettlementView = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.mode_hunt = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
    Me.mode_forage = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
    CType(Me.PicWorldMap, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.picPortrait, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.picScene, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.picSky, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'GameTimer
    '
    Me.GameTimer.Enabled = True
    Me.GameTimer.Interval = 1000
    '
    'GameMsgBox
    '
    Me.GameMsgBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(194, 596)
    Me.GameMsgBox.Name = "GameMsgBox"
    Me.GameMsgBox.ReadOnly = True
    Me.GameMsgBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(571, 91)
    Me.GameMsgBox.TabIndex = 0
    Me.GameMsgBox.Text = ""
    '
    'GameMsgFilter
    '
    Me.GameMsgFilter.CheckOnClick = True
    Me.GameMsgFilter.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.GameMsgFilter.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"General", "Important", "Ambient", "Combat", "New Items"})
    Me.GameMsgFilter.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(771, 598)
    Me.GameMsgFilter.Name = "GameMsgFilter"
    Me.GameMsgFilter.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(128, 89)
    Me.GameMsgFilter.TabIndex = 1
    '
    'PicWorldMap
    '
    Me.PicWorldMap.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(192, 176)
    Me.PicWorldMap.Name = "PicWorldMap"
    Me.PicWorldMap.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(707, 414)
    Me.PicWorldMap.TabIndex = 2
    Me.PicWorldMap.TabStop = False
    '
    'mapAreaTitle
    '
    Me.mapAreaTitle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(192, 148)
    Me.mapAreaTitle.Name = "mapAreaTitle"
    Me.mapAreaTitle.ReadOnly = True
    Me.mapAreaTitle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(662, 22)
    Me.mapAreaTitle.TabIndex = 3
    Me.mapAreaTitle.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center
    '
    'lblCrafting
    '
    Me.lblCrafting.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(849, 26)
    Me.lblCrafting.Name = "lblCrafting"
    Me.lblCrafting.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 44)
    Me.lblCrafting.TabIndex = 4
    Me.lblCrafting.Text = "[craft]"
    '
    'barHP
    '
    Me.barHP.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    Me.barHP.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(72, 30)
    Me.barHP.Name = "barHP"
    Me.barHP.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(40, 10)
    Me.barHP.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    Me.barHP.TabIndex = 5
    '
    'barMagic
    '
    Me.barMagic.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Fuchsia
    Me.barMagic.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(72, 62)
    Me.barMagic.Name = "barMagic"
    Me.barMagic.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(40, 10)
    Me.barMagic.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    Me.barMagic.TabIndex = 6
    '
    'barStamina
    '
    Me.barStamina.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(192, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(192, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer))
    Me.barStamina.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(72, 46)
    Me.barStamina.Name = "barStamina"
    Me.barStamina.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(40, 10)
    Me.barStamina.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    Me.barStamina.TabIndex = 7
    '
    'barHunger
    '
    Me.barHunger.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(255, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(128, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer))
    Me.barHunger.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(127, 29)
    Me.barHunger.Name = "barHunger"
    Me.barHunger.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(49, 10)
    Me.barHunger.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    Me.barHunger.TabIndex = 8
    '
    'barThirst
    '
    Me.barThirst.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(128, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(255, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(255, Byte), Integer))
    Me.barThirst.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(127, 45)
    Me.barThirst.Name = "barThirst"
    Me.barThirst.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(49, 10)
    Me.barThirst.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    Me.barThirst.TabIndex = 9
    '
    'barRest
    '
    Me.barRest.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
    Me.barRest.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(127, 62)
    Me.barRest.Name = "barRest"
    Me.barRest.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(49, 10)
    Me.barRest.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    Me.barRest.TabIndex = 10
    '
    'picPortrait
    '
    Me.picPortrait.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 26)
    Me.picPortrait.Name = "picPortrait"
    Me.picPortrait.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 50)
    Me.picPortrait.TabIndex = 11
    Me.picPortrait.TabStop = False
    '
    'picScene
    '
    Me.picScene.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(324, 26)
    Me.picScene.Name = "picScene"
    Me.picScene.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(160, 80)
    Me.picScene.TabIndex = 13
    Me.picScene.TabStop = False
    '
    'picSky
    '
    Me.picSky.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(496, 26)
    Me.picSky.Name = "picSky"
    Me.picSky.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(160, 80)
    Me.picSky.TabIndex = 14
    Me.picSky.TabStop = False
    '
    'lblTimeNormal
    '
    Me.lblTimeNormal.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblTimeNormal.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(591, 108)
    Me.lblTimeNormal.Name = "lblTimeNormal"
    Me.lblTimeNormal.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(19, 19)
    Me.lblTimeNormal.TabIndex = 15
    Me.lblTimeNormal.Text = ">"
    Me.lblTimeNormal.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    '
    'lblTimeFast
    '
    Me.lblTimeFast.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblTimeFast.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(616, 108)
    Me.lblTimeFast.Name = "lblTimeFast"
    Me.lblTimeFast.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(19, 19)
    Me.lblTimeFast.TabIndex = 16
    Me.lblTimeFast.Text = ">>"
    Me.lblTimeFast.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    '
    'lblTimeFaster
    '
    Me.lblTimeFaster.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblTimeFaster.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(641, 108)
    Me.lblTimeFaster.Name = "lblTimeFaster"
    Me.lblTimeFaster.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(19, 19)
    Me.lblTimeFaster.TabIndex = 17
    Me.lblTimeFaster.Text = ">>>"
    Me.lblTimeFaster.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    '
    'lblTimeDate
    '
    Me.lblTimeDate.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblTimeDate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(319, 108)
    Me.lblTimeDate.Name = "lblTimeDate"
    Me.lblTimeDate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(267, 19)
    Me.lblTimeDate.TabIndex = 18
    Me.lblTimeDate.Text = ">"
    Me.lblTimeDate.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    '
    'ActionList
    '
    Me.ActionList.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    Me.ActionList.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    Me.ActionList.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader() {Me.ColumnHeader2})
    Me.ActionList.FullRowSelect = True
    Me.ActionList.GridLines = True
    Me.ActionList.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(11, 148)
    Me.ActionList.MultiSelect = False
    Me.ActionList.Name = "ActionList"
    Me.ActionList.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(165, 442)
    Me.ActionList.TabIndex = 20
    Me.ActionList.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = False
    Me.ActionList.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
    '
    'ColumnHeader2
    '
    Me.ColumnHeader2.Text = "Available Actions"
    Me.ColumnHeader2.Width = 163
    '
    'lblCharSheet
    '
    Me.lblCharSheet.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(793, 26)
    Me.lblCharSheet.Name = "lblCharSheet"
    Me.lblCharSheet.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 44)
    Me.lblCharSheet.TabIndex = 21
    Me.lblCharSheet.Text = "[Char Sheet]"
    '
    'lblCurrentAction
    '
    Me.lblCurrentAction.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblCurrentAction.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 79)
    Me.lblCurrentAction.Name = "lblCurrentAction"
    Me.lblCurrentAction.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(164, 19)
    Me.lblCurrentAction.TabIndex = 22
    Me.lblCurrentAction.Text = ">"
    Me.lblCurrentAction.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    '
    'TM_Walk
    '
    Me.TM_Walk.AutoSize = True
    Me.TM_Walk.Checked = True
    Me.TM_Walk.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.TM_Walk.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(11, 596)
    Me.TM_Walk.Name = "TM_Walk"
    Me.TM_Walk.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(49, 19)
    Me.TM_Walk.TabIndex = 23
    Me.TM_Walk.TabStop = True
    Me.TM_Walk.Text = "Walk"
    Me.TM_Walk.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'TM_run
    '
    Me.TM_run.AutoSize = True
    Me.TM_run.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.TM_run.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(11, 621)
    Me.TM_run.Name = "TM_run"
    Me.TM_run.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(44, 19)
    Me.TM_run.TabIndex = 24
    Me.TM_run.Text = "Run"
    Me.TM_run.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'TM_sprint
    '
    Me.TM_sprint.AutoSize = True
    Me.TM_sprint.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.TM_sprint.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(11, 646)
    Me.TM_sprint.Name = "TM_sprint"
    Me.TM_sprint.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(54, 19)
    Me.TM_sprint.TabIndex = 25
    Me.TM_sprint.Text = "Sprint"
    Me.TM_sprint.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'lblOptions
    '
    Me.lblOptions.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(849, 78)
    Me.lblOptions.Name = "lblOptions"
    Me.lblOptions.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 44)
    Me.lblOptions.TabIndex = 26
    Me.lblOptions.Text = "[options]"
    '
    'lblSettlementView
    '
    Me.lblSettlementView.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(860, 148)
    Me.lblSettlementView.Name = "lblSettlementView"
    Me.lblSettlementView.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 22)
    Me.lblSettlementView.TabIndex = 27
    Me.lblSettlementView.Text = "[SV]"
    Me.lblSettlementView.Visible = False
    '
    'mode_hunt
    '
    Me.mode_hunt.AutoSize = True
    Me.mode_hunt.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.mode_hunt.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(192, 19)
    Me.mode_hunt.Name = "mode_hunt"
    Me.mode_hunt.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(79, 19)
    Me.mode_hunt.TabIndex = 28
    Me.mode_hunt.Text = "Hunt Mode"
    Me.mode_hunt.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'mode_forage
    '
    Me.mode_forage.AutoSize = True
    Me.mode_forage.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.mode_forage.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(192, 37)
    Me.mode_forage.Name = "mode_forage"
    Me.mode_forage.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(90, 19)
    Me.mode_forage.TabIndex = 29
    Me.mode_forage.Text = "Forage mode"
    Me.mode_forage.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'frmMainGame
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(7.0!, 17.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.BackgroundImage = Global.ProjectKeira.My.Resources.Resources.main_base1
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(918, 700)
    Me.ControlBox = False
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.mode_forage)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.mode_hunt)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblSettlementView)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblOptions)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TM_sprint)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TM_run)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TM_Walk)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblCurrentAction)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblCharSheet)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.ActionList)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblTimeDate)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblTimeFaster)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblTimeFast)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblTimeNormal)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.picSky)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.picScene)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.picPortrait)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.barRest)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.barThirst)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.barHunger)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.barStamina)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.barMagic)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.barHP)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblCrafting)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.mapAreaTitle)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.PicWorldMap)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.GameMsgFilter)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.GameMsgBox)
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.Name = "frmMainGame"
    Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Me.Text = "MainGame"
    CType(Me.PicWorldMap, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.picPortrait, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.picScene, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.picSky, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub

Friend WithEvents GameTimer As Timer
Friend WithEvents GameMsgBox As RichTextBox
Friend WithEvents GameMsgFilter As CheckedListBox
Friend WithEvents PicWorldMap As PictureBox
Friend WithEvents mapAreaTitle As TextBox
Friend WithEvents lblCrafting As Label
Friend WithEvents barHP As ProgressBar
Friend WithEvents barMagic As ProgressBar
Friend WithEvents barStamina As ProgressBar
Friend WithEvents barHunger As ProgressBar
Friend WithEvents barThirst As ProgressBar
Friend WithEvents barRest As ProgressBar
Friend WithEvents picPortrait As PictureBox
Friend WithEvents picScene As PictureBox
Friend WithEvents picSky As PictureBox
Friend WithEvents lblTimeNormal As Label
Friend WithEvents lblTimeFast As Label
Friend WithEvents lblTimeFaster As Label
Friend WithEvents lblTimeDate As Label
Friend WithEvents ActionList As ListView
Friend WithEvents ColumnHeader2 As ColumnHeader
Friend WithEvents lblCharSheet As Label
Friend WithEvents lblCurrentAction As Label
Friend WithEvents TM_Walk As RadioButton
Friend WithEvents TM_run As RadioButton
Friend WithEvents TM_sprint As RadioButton
Friend WithEvents lblOptions As Label
Friend WithEvents lblSettlementView As Label
Friend WithEvents mode_hunt As CheckBox
Friend WithEvents mode_forage As CheckBox
End Class
```

Comment: Firstly - you do know that Forms *are* classes don't you? Secondly - what do you mean by sub controls?

Comment: @MattWilko : I think he means that he can only find his form as if it were a base class, with no controls included. -- Shaun, are you trying to reference the current form? In that case you should use `Me` instead of the form's name. Please post a screenshot, or two, showing the problem.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I do understand that Forms are Classes, however my precise terminology is very poor. I've added two screenshots of an extract of code where the error can clearly be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to use the default instance of a form.
If so then that behavior is a bug in Visual Studio which might get fixed or not.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760659/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-not-displaying-all-methods) they know of it since update 1 but it is still there after update 3.

Meanwhile you can either create an instance of your form and use that

```
Dim f as new frmMainGame
f.something()
```

or if you need the default instance you can access it with

```
My.Forms.frmMainGame.something()
```

Comment: That's why using default instances is bad!  I wish MS would just eliminate that dubious "feature".